# Chain to another controller setup with a variable URL Mapping

Tags: grails

I'm trying to chain from one controller to another. However, the controller I'm chaining to contains a variable in its URL Mapping, e.g.:

```
"/go/$var?/a" ( controller: "a", action: "show" )
```

For some reason, when I chain from controller b -> a:

```
chain(controller: "a", action: "show", model: model)
```

Grails redirects the page to `/go`. Then, when I change the URL mapping to:

```
"/go/a" ( controller: "a", action: "show" )
```

(i.e. without a var) my chain works fine.

It's as if the chain to a, when the URL with `$var?` is present, needs the value `$var?` set somewhere.

**Question**

Is there any way to chain to another controller when that controller's URLMapping contains a var in it? Is my only solution to go with the URI approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to this, use 'params':

```
chain(controller: "a", action: "show", model: model, params: [var: "abc"])
```